# $P(P(\cdots(P(x))))$ and its integer solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, functions, graphing-functions

**Problem**: Suppose that $P(x)$ is a polynomial with degree at least $2$ and integer coefficients. Let $Q(x)$ have the form $$ Q(x) = P(P(P(\cdots P(x) \cdots))) $$ for some finite number of nested $P$s. Prove that the equation $Q(t)=t$ can have at most $ \text {deg}(P) $ integer solutions.

**Thoughts**: Graphing it doesn't help as the key to this problem is the *integer* restriction. Taking inverses don't help as they are ugly to deal with. Induction, maybe? But how?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this an old IMO problem?

Comment: Really? I tried looking this problem up and didn't find it. Which year is it?

Comment: Is it possible to start with finding the solutions of $Q(t)=0$?  That problem seems very easy...

Comment: Vincent, based on the fact its a problem I have absolutely no idea how one would go about solving, that sounds about right :)

Comment: @AhaanRungta http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/2006_IMO_Problems/Problem_5

Comment: Yep, dinoboy mentioned it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [IMO 2006 Problem 5](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=572821&sid=308156b3a776a401a4f4fea55a62d164#p572821)

A solution to it is this:

Suppose $a$ is a solution to $Q(x) = x$.
Let $a_0 = a$ and $P^m(a) = a_m$.
Then we know $(a_z - a_{z-1})|(a_{z+1}-a_z)$ for all $z \ge 1$. In particular, $(a_k - a_{k-1})|(a_1 - a_0)$ so we quickly deduce that $P$ has order $2$ on $a$ or order $1$. 
This is because firstly we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{a_{i+1} - a_{i}}{a_{i} - a_{i-1}} = 1 \implies \frac{a_{i+1} - a_{i}}{a_{i} - a_{i-1}} = \pm  1$$ Now suppose $m$ is the minimum number of $P$'s you need to apply on $a$ to reach $a$ again where $m > 1$. Then the $a_i$ are distinct. One quickly deduces if one of them were $-1$, we would have $a_{i+1} = a_{i-1}$ which implies $m=2$. Thus we can assume all of them are equal to $1$, but then the $a_i$ form an arithmetic progression which is absurd. Thus it is only possible $m=1$ or $m=2$.

Now, $P(x) = x$ has at most $\deg P$ solutions. Thus if there does not exist an $a$ such that $P(P(a)) = a$ while $P(a) \neq a$, we are done.
Now suppose $P(P(a)) = a$ and $P(a) = b$ and $P(c) = d, P(d) = c$.
Then $(a-c)|(b-d)$ and $(b-d)|(a-c) \implies a-c = \pm (b-d)$. One also knows $(a-d)|(b-c)$ and $(b-c)|(a-d) \implies a-d = \pm(b-c)$.
But then one quickly deduces $a+b = c+d$. Note that this implies if $P(z) = z$ then $2z = a+b$ by letting $c=d=z$. Now let $a$ be a solution to $P(P(a)) = a$. Then any $z$ such that $Q(z) = z$ is a root of $x + P(x) - a - P(a)$, which has at most $\deg P$ roots so we are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and nice to see you here! Accepted, but will upvote once my vote lock is off.

Answer (score 0):

The degree of a polynomial $P$ can be found by the limit $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {x\cdot (P(x))'}{P(x)}$$

Suppose that there are only two compositions(for simplicity),then we have that $$deg(Q)=deg(P)^{2}=>degQ=\lim_{x\to \infty} (\frac {x\cdot (P(x))'}{P(x)})^2$$

Now $$deg(Q-I)=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {x\cdot (Q(x)-x)'}{Q(x)-x}$$ where $I$ is the identity function.

Try to show that $ deg(Q-I)\leq degP$.