# Trouble understanding a number theory problem related to polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I am following, titu's book on number theory, the level of examples is escalating at a very quick rate which caused me trouble understanding them.
The problem is as follows:
Let $f$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, of degree $n≥2$,Prove that the equation $$f(f(x)) = x$$ has at most $n$ integral solutions.
The author has started the solution by considering another solution to the equation, let it be $y$.

Clearly, $$x-y=f(f(x))-f(f(y))$$
Which is a multiple of $f(x)-f(y)$ and $x-y$.
I understood everything pretty well till here.
In the next part, the author considers integers $a_1<a_2..<a_d$ which satisfy $$f(f(a_i))$$ with $i$ ranging between 1 and $d$.
Next, he proves that the sequence $f(a_i)$ is either increasing or decreasing, and thereby concluding that $f(a_{i+1}) - f(a_i) = a_{i+1} - a_i$(for the case that it is increasing specifically)
Which implies, there exist a number c such that $$f(a_i)-a_i=c$$
Which can have atmost degree $n$,
I am not able to understand the motivation behind such an approach.

Comment: Where in the book can you find the problem?

Comment: It is an example in the first chapter

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1385387p7702139). See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574919/pp-cdotspx-and-its-integer-solutions?noredirect=1).

Comment: Sorry, but i still am not able to understand it.